# how to get the next 2Dpoint in the frame

Tags: opencv

I use opencv & Notebook Camera. So I want to find four special object. I had solved it. So I get four 2DPoint. At the next frame, I find four 2DPoint of object. But I want to match 2DPoint of first frame to 2DPoint of second frame. 
All object light white light.
Looking forward your positive reply.

Comment: Looking forward for a more detailed question :D

Comment: I want to track the same four objects. when I enter unique number of each object of first frame, I want to represent unique number at next frame.

Comment: post sample images with sample points.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a four points of your object you can use Optical-Flow.

```
std::vector<cv::Point> prev{p1,p2,p3,p4};
std::vector<cv::Point> next;
cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
  mat_prev, mat_next, 
  prev,
  next, 
  status, 
  err  
);
```

[Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#void%20calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(InputArray%20prevImg,%20InputArray%20nextImg,%20InputArray%20prevPts,%20InputOutputArray%20nextPts,%20OutputArray%20status,%20OutputArray%20err,%20Size%20winSize,%20int%20maxLevel,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20flags,%20double%20minEigThreshold))